# how to setup self connection to google_compute_instance_template for file provisioning

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to do a file provisioned into `google_compute_instance_template` using the method shown below

```
...
  provisioner "file" {
      source = file("${path.module}/../scripts/infrastructure/circleci/docker-compose.production.yml")
      destination = "/tmp/docker_compose_file"

      connection {
        host = google_compute_instance_template.media_apps_template.self_link.public_ip
        agent = false
        type = "ssh"
        user = "ubuntu"
        private_key = "${file("./creds/media_apps")}"
      }
  }

....
```

the parent `google_compute_instance_template` looks like this

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "media_apps_template" {

}
```

The error am getting is
`Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).`

How can I configure the host part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 ​   ​connection​ { 
 ​     type ​=​ ​"​ssh​" 
 ​     user ​=​ ​"​ubuntu​" 
 ​     private_key ​=​ ​file​(​"​./creds/media_apps​.pem"​) 
 ​     host ​=​ google_compute_instance_template.self_link.public_ip
```